# MS Access: Reset input field in form to default value 0 upon exit form

Tags: sql, ms-access

**EDIT: The fields shown in pictures below all have "value list" as row source type. The input in these fields are used in queries that pull data from tables as well, but these fields themselves do not use any tables.**

I have a form in Access that requires users to provide input via listboxes, and then queries use that data to perform calculations.
However,when the entire access file is closed, the same input values are still in the listbox after reopening.

Ideally I want the values in the input fields to default to 0 (not null) as soon as the access file is closed (or re-opened), so when the user opens the database, he will see the value "0" in those fields. The reason to why I want the value 0 as default is because the inputboxes reflect possible commodities a product can contain, and I want to allow users to define the % commodity a product does or does not contain. 0 means the product does not contain that commodity and the user does not have to change the value in the listbox (more user friendly in my opinion). Picture illustration:

[image]

Hence each time I re-open the access file, I keep seeing those input values above, while I want them to be 0.

I did some research but don't really understand how to use the expression builder, and I can't find a way to make it work via a macro. I read something about the listboxes having to be 'bound', but I'm not entirely sure how to deal with this.

This is the above listboxes in design view:

[image]

Comment: If there is no table sitting behind that form, those values would not be persisted after closing.  Are you sure there is no code running behind the scenes (maybe Form_Load or Form_Current) which is attaching a RecordSource property to your form?

Comment: @VBlades I edited my question, but in short: these fields are pure value lists, no tables behind the fields. In that same form, calculation output is shown by queries who pull data from tables, thus there is code running behind the form. I'm not sure where to identify form_load or form_current.

Answer (score 1):

You are using listboxes but at a height of one selection which is not the optimal use for such a form control as no multiple listing is shown at once together.

Consider using free-form textboxes with a default value of zero. But if you need to control a user's input, use combo boxes which defaults to the zero selection item. Most likely right now, each listbox is defaulting to its first selection item.

Here is how the Property Sheet / Data Tab of the combox would look (in fact Default Value might be redundant as zero is the first item):

```
Row Source     : 0;20;40;60
Row Source Type: Value List

...


Default Value  : 0
```

If combo boxes use a table/query row source, you will need to append a value of zero with a UNION query:

```
Row Source     : SELECT TOP 1 0 AS ColName FROM TableName UNION SELECT Val FROM TableName;
Row Source Type: Table/Query

...


Default Value  : 0
```

Comment: In the case of the combobox solution - would this prevent my user from entering any number they want? In your example, could they only select 0-20-40-60, and not for example write down 78?

Comment: Correct. Combo boxes are controlled value inputs limited to value choices available as opposed to free form textboxes.

Comment: I cannot limit the value choices for the users, hence I believe free form textboxes will be a better option. If I use text boxes, would queries still be able to read these values, perform calculations and provide output? I want to avoid changing my listboxes and then realizing I cannot perform any calculation.

Comment: Yes, queries can use various data input form controls including textboxes, checkboxes, comboboxes, listboxes.

Comment: Awwww! What happened? You could not change the listboxes to comboboxes? Or free-form textboxes? Do queries referencing the form controls not work?

Comment: when I use textboxes, the queries are not using the input - no calculations are performed.I simply replaced my listboxes with text boxes and adjusted the query code to refer to textboxes instead of listboxes, so im not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: Is the form opened when queries run as it must since textboxes are unbound? And are you properly using the [nomenclature](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm): `Forms!frmname!textboxname`? If using a subform: `Forms!frmname!subfrmname.Form!subfrmtextboxname`. Also, do forgive me but this latter issue is not your original question as you originally needed the default zeros in input boxes, not query handling.

Comment: The form is opened when the queries run. I have no subforms, and am using the nomenclature as you mentioned. I know it's not the original issue - i'm sorry if i'm going off-topic. It's a huge form, so it may be that one query is not using the correct named textbox or so, I'm digging to it currently. I don't get any errors when writing down numbers in the textboxes and running the queries, but no output is provided anymore. The output-boxes remain blank, while when the textboxes were listboxes, output was shown.

Comment: Without seeing more, I cannot help. If you can send me an abbreviated version of database with specific form and queries by Dropbox/Google Drive/OneDrive. Or post one query's SQL to see if you are properly referencing form control.